# How to do validation on form submit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have three textbox, where i am replacing `%` with `-` on keyup. But i want to perform this on submit. I don't want to show the replacement to user but on submit it should get replaced. Don't know much about jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, "-"));
      });
});

$(function() {
    $('#userName').keyup(function() {
          $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, ""-""));
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#productCode').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, ""-""));
    });
});

 First name: <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
  First name: <input type="text" name="userName" ><br>
   First name: <input type="text" name="productCode" ><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: If this is a matter of validating input, it should really be done server-side. There's no guarantee the user won't change/disable your JS and send invalid input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can sumbit another form or use hidden fields.
2. You don't need to wrap each individual block of code in `$(function(){});`.

> That's a shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){});

```js
var doReplace = function(string){
        return string.replace(/%/g, "-");
}

var $nameX = $('#nameX');
var $userX = $('#userNameX');
var $prodX = $('#productCodeX');

$('#name').keyup(function() {
  $nameX.val(doReplace($(this).val()));
});

$('#userName').keyup(function() {
  $userX.val(doReplace($(this).val()));
});

$('#productCode').keyup(function() {
  $prodX.val(doReplace($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="hidden" id="nameX" name="name" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="userName" />
  <input type="hidden" id="userNameX" name="userName" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="productCode" />
  <input type="hidden" id="productCodeX" name="productCode" /><br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**OR AT FORM SUBMIT**

```js
var doReplace = function(string){
  return string.replace(/%/g, "-");
}

var $nameX = $('#nameX');
var $userX = $('#userNameX');
var $prodX = $('#productCodeX');

$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  $nameX.val(doReplace($('#name').val()));
  $userX.val(doReplace($('#userName').val()));
  $prodX.val(doReplace($('#productCode').val()));

  console.log($nameX.val());
  console.log($userX.val());
  console.log($prodX.val());
  
  // Remove this in production. Here it's just so we can see the console log.
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="hidden" id="nameX" name="name" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="userName" />
  <input type="hidden" id="userNameX" name="userName" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="productCode" />
  <input type="hidden" id="productCodeX" name="productCode" /><br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Working fiddle ==> http://jsfiddle.net/y4a7rp2e/

Comment: The `name` attributes need to be re-added, and the "x" fields need to be `type="hidden"`.

Comment: exactly. Fixing immediately

Comment: I would suggest the `name` attributes should be without the additional "X" on the hidden inputs to avoid changing server-side code to accept the correct fields. Perhaps the `name` attributes for the visible inputs should be dropped completely, since we're not using those values server-side.

Comment: Excellent tip. Doing it.

Comment: @Janny can you expand on that?

Comment: i wanted it work on form submit, but it doesnt seem to work. @mac9416

Comment: @Janny so.... console error, unexpected values server-side? What precisely is happening in an undesired way, and in what way is it not desired?

Comment: Actually from backend side its shows POST http:/services 400 (), because on from submit backend will not accept % sign but what i can see on submit from is that its not replacing % , on console i can see name%^username^id when i entered name with % sign @mac9416

Comment: I'm putting this in a fiddle

Comment: @FrankCadillac same. But you really gotta test the snippets before saving edits. Just fixed some bugs.

Comment: @mac9416 you only made the embedded snippets work. I never used those. But I will now on. I didn't know that by adding `<script>` tags it would actually load scripts...So I always thought that jQuery snippets would never work. Glad to be wrong then. Cheers

Comment: @FrankCadillac ah, fair. Love it when technology is surprisingly good.

Comment: @mac9416 ahahah me too :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTMl code :

```
 First Name: <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
 User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" ><br>
 Product Code: <input type="text" name="productCode" ><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit>
```

In order to perform the replacement assign an id to Submit button, Use the id and replace

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').submit(function() {
            $('#name').val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, "-"));
            $('#userName').val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, ""-""));
            $('#productCode').val($(this).val().replace(/[%]/g, ""-""));
      });
    })
```

So when submit button is clicked all the 3 fields will perform the operations Specified. The operations can also be changed

For more information regarding the .submit() in jQuery refer to the official Documentation : https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Doesn't keep the changes invisible to the user.

Comment: Also, it's not **JQuery**. It's **jQuery**.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, name the 3 functions you have for validating your html.
You can use `.submit` or `.click` functions.

**For .click :**

```
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">

$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
    //call the 3 functions by name
});
```

**for .submit:** 
enclose your form between `<form></form>` tags

```
$("yourformName").submit(function(){
    //call the 3 functions by name
});
```